# C++: hiding some functions

Tags: c++, math, namespaces, header, scope

I redefined some maths functions (so that they're faster -ie: less accurate-, or use templates). I put these functions in a namespace and they work just fine.

It happens often, though, that I forget to call functions from my namespace (ie: I forget to write `mymath::cos` or `using mymath::cos;` when I want to call `cos`), and it's pretty tough to find out where I forgot it (until now I found it out only by profiling).

Given that

- I **only** include standard `math.h` or `cmath` headers within my math header, and that
- I need to include standard math headers (because some of my functions are just wrappers for standard one, and I want them to be inline or they're templated),

is there a portable way to *hide* standard math function so that a compile error is reported, if global namespace (ie: without a namespace) math functions are used?

A solution could be putting an `using namespace mymath;` at the bottom of my math header file, but this solution doesn't seem that great: it breaks the whole purpose of namespaces; I'd prefer having to explicity say whether to use a function from `mymath` or from `std` so that I am forced to choose between a fester or a more accurate function without the risk of forgetting about it.

---

**EDIT**:

Many answers say that if I use `cos` from global namespace (without using `std` nor `mymath`), and include `cmath` (and not `math.h`), compilation should fail.

I don't know what the standard says about it, but:

```
#include <cmath>
int main( ) {
    cos( M_PI );
    return 0;
}
```

compiles fine with GNU GCC (`g++`) 4.5.1 (and older versions).

Comment: You're correct regarding the EDIT: "It is unspecified whether these names are first declared within the global namespace scope and are then injected into namespace std by explicit using-declarations".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this in a header file, and #include it everywhere:

```
namespace DontUseMe {  
double cos (double) ;  
// ...etc.  
}  
using namespace DontUseMe ;
```

Comment: Uh, this looks nice! Using Boost.StaticAssert it will give me compile time errors whenever I use a global namespace math function...

Comment: When you do this and in some compilation unit `cmath` is included, the compiler will tell you that `double cos(double)` is ambiguous. Hence the namespace *wrestling* ;)

Comment: @Fritschy: That's the whole point! It forces an explicit namespace qualifier. Which is exactly what OP wanted.

Comment: OK, TonyK, :) haven't thought of purposefully breaking a program :).

Answer (score 2):

If you only include `cmath` and not `math.h`, all functions from that header should be in the std:: namespace. Just never use `using namespace std;` and you'll be fine. (`cmath` is just `math.h` with all things in a namespace)

Comment: Nope, not with `cmath` from GNU GCC 4.5.1. I mean, yeah, it provides math functions in `std` namespace, but it **also** provides math functions at global namespace (ie: `::cos`, without any namespace), which is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to include the math.h and cmath headers directly in your header file? If you do need to, try including the header like this:

```
namespace arbitrary_name
{
  #include <math.h>
}
```

This will contain all of the math.h definitions inside a new namespace, so you won't accidentally use them elsewhere.

This is not ideal solution. Perhaps there is a better way to do this using anonymous namespaces, but the solution isn't clear to me.

Comment: This will work, but only if `math.h` contains C code only. I'd prefer to include `cmath`, so that it declares many overloaded functions with the same name of standard functions (ie: `double cos(double x);`, `float cos(float x);` ...). -- Anyway I think this is the best I can do...

Comment: The River, this won't work as all symbols exported by that lib aren't in the namespace you put the header in.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the most robust solution will be to not use the same function names as the standard library.  Luckily the standard function names are terse and heavily abbreviated so names such as `cosine()`, `sine()`, `exponent()`, `arctan()` would be unique (and arguably better) without having to adorn the name with clumsy prefixes.

Alternatively you might keep the same names but capitalise them:  `Sin()`, `Cos()`, `Exp()` etc.

Comment: It'll of course work, but as I forget to explicitly use a given namespace, I'm sure I'll often forget to use my custom names for standard functions. However it'd be easier to find where I use standard function names...

Comment: I'd rather go for full name than play on capitalization.

Comment: @Matthieu:  I entirely agree, it's horrible but may appeal to some.

Answer (score 1):

How about this idea: after including < math.h>, use define as follows:

```
#define sin blahblahblah    (just to generate an error)
#define cos blahblahblah    (just to generate an error)
```

What happens is that every sin will be replaced by blahblahblah, which will cause an error. But what will happen is that mymath::sin will be replaced by mymath::blahblahblah (because #define works literally), so it will also generate an error. In this case, if you want to make the task easier for you just temporarily define the function blahblahblah in mymath to avoid showing error for mymath::sin, then compile, and fix all those errors.

However, I would recommend just making "Find in Files" and going through all the functions, and I am sure it will not talk you more than an hour for a very large scale project.

Hope that helps.

Regards,
Rafid

Comment: This is a possible solution. The standard math functions from the standard library are often macros.

Comment: Hum, was hoping to find a way to do this at compile time, without having two steps for compiling (one to check functions validity, and the other to actually compile)... Anyway yes, this would work.

Comment: This won't work, you would have to define them as function style macros and you would have to check and `undef` them as they are allowed to be macros (as well as functions) in `math.h`. If you use non-function style macros then any attempt to use `(std::sin)(x)` or `(mymath::sin)(y)` would still be mangled by these macros.

Comment: This is not allowed: "A translation unit that includes a standard library header shall not #define or #undef names declared in
any standard library header"

Comment: @Charles, yes, they are non-function macro style, which is only used to make a remapping for functions names. I already explained this in my answer, this is why I suggested he define the function blahblahblah in mymath namespace.

Comment: So how is he supposed to call (e.g.) the original `std::sin` or `mymath::cos` which he wants to be able to do if `sin` and `cos` are defined as macros to a dummy `blahblahblah` ?

Comment: As far as I understood, he just wants to remove all the calls to the default sin and cos, so he asked for some way to generate an error in case he calls those sin and cos. The method I suggested allow him to do this, then he can replace all these calls with mymath::sin and mymath::cos, then remove the #define's. Won't that work?

Answer (score 1):

Write some wrapper functions in a separate file.

```
#include <math.h>

namespace my_wrapper
{

float sin(float n)
{
    return std::sin(float n);
}

};
```

Or something like that. And then only use those in your other files and don't even include  or  in the other soure files. Yes it's a small pain to write forwarding functions for them all but it's just a one off job and there aren't that many...

With a modern compiler that does link time code generation and can inline across object files this shouldn't be inefficient...

Comment: How about templates? `template< typename T1, typename T2 > PROMOTE(T1,T2) pow( T1 x, T2 y ) { return std::pow( (PROMOTE(T1,T2)) x, (PROMOTE(T1,T2)) y ); }` ? (`PROMOTE` is a macro I defined that uses templates to promote types - ie: PROMOTE(int,double) is double).

Answer (score 0):

Clifford's my favorite answer so far, but there is another alternative you might envisage: modify the standard headers for this project (only).

There should be an option with your compiler of choice to indicate where the standard library lies, therefore you can duplicate the STL in your project, and modify the files so that the offending names are no longer injected in the global namespace.

It is hackish, but that's the only way I can think of, short of checking the code with a script for any occurrence of `cos` / `sin` that is not qualified (ie immediately preceded by `::`).